# Historical Options data

Tags: options, quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, historical-data, option-data

Are there any good sources where I can obtain daily historical options data (strike price, expiration dates, bid/ask spread, etc).

I understand that this type of data is very hard to come by and almost impossible to find (reliable) free data; therefore I do not mind paying.

Also would anyone have any recommendations on how to backtest a covered call strategy without historical data, if even possible. I am using python.

Comment: Did searching for "Option Data" in here help you in any way? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/daily-option-data https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8735/cme-historical-option-data-provider https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/23110/where-can-i-find-best-end-of-day-option-data https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online

Answer (score 1):

A reliable and goods source is ORATS it is priced reasonably though not altogether cheap, you can get it from Quandl or Orats themselves, I only subscribe for the equities and ETFs market back to 2007, it costs me $50 USD,  monthly,$66 AUD, monthly I actually pay. It is far more than just historical prices it is charts, backtester, scanner, all variations of implied and historical volatilities and greeks, etc, very good service.